# Criterion for local integrability of $1/f$ for $f$ a smooth function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb C$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a function $f=u+iv$, $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ which is smooth, in the sense that $u$ and $v$ are smooth. I am wondering what some criteria are for
$$
\int_{B_r(x_0,y_0)}\frac1 f\mathrm dA(x,y)
$$
to converge in some suitable sense, where $\mathrm dA(x,y)$ is the area measure. For example, if $f(x_0,y_0)=0$ but $f$ has no other zeros in the ball, is it enough to have $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\ne 0$?

Presumably, what I am asking is equivalent to asking if
$$
\int_{B_r(x_0,y_0)}\frac {u} {u^2+v^2}\mathrm dA(x,y)
$$
and
$$
\int_{B_r(x_0,y_0)}\frac {v} {u^2+v^2}\mathrm dA(x,y)
$$
converge separately.

Comment: Have you considered polar coordinates centered at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I did, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think you will need both components of $\nabla f$ to be nonzero. Have you written this out? Edit your post to include your efforts.

Comment: @TedShifrin I can add the integral in polar coordinates, but I didn't get much farther than that. The jacobian seems helpful, but then I didn't see how to incorporate the gradient condition.

Comment: @foreverstudent Does convergence of $\int \frac{1}{f} dA$ mean in the Lebesgue sense?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, in the Lebesgue sesne.

Comment: @zhw. That example vanishes on the line $x=0$.

Comment: @foreverstudent Gasp, I keep making the dumbest mistakes on your problem. Will delete, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I set $z_0 = (x_0,y_0)$.

I strengthen a bit the assumptions.

If the differential $\mathrm{d}f(z_0)$ is invertible and if $f$ has no zero but $z_0$ on the closed ball $\overline{B}_{r}(z_0)$, the desired conclusion holds. Indeed, by local incversion theorem, $f$ restricted to some neighborhood of $z_0$ to its image is invertible, and $\mathrm{d}f^{-1}(0) = \mathrm{d}f(z_0)^{-1}$.

For all small enough $h$, we have $h = f^{-1}(f(z_0+h)) - f^{-1}(f(z_0))$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$ and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(z_0)$, we derive that when $h \to 0$,
$$h =  \mathrm{d}f^{-1}(f(z_0))(f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)) + o(||f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)||).$$
$$h = \mathrm{d}f^{-1}(f(z_0))(f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)) + o(||h||).$$
Since $f(z_0)=0$, we get
$$||h|| \le ||\mathrm{d}f^{-1}(0)|| \times ||f(z_0+h)|| + o(||h||).$$
The map $h \mapsto ||f(z_0+h)||/||h||$ does not vanish and is is continuous on $\overline{B}_{r}(0) \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, and it is bounded away from $0$ at the neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Using the compactness of $\overline{B_r(0)} \setminus B_\delta(0)$
for $0<\delta<r$, one sees that there exists some $c>0$ such that $||f(z_0+h)|| \ge c||h||$ for every $h \in \overline{B}_r(0) \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Hence
$$\int_{\overline{B_r(0)}} \frac{1}{||f(z_0+h)||}dh \le \int_{\overline{B}_r(0)} \frac{c}{||h)||}dh = \int_0^r \frac{c}{\rho}\rho \mathrm{d}\rho\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta = 2\pi cr < +\infty.$$
Hence, the integral of $1/f$ on $\overline{B}_r(0)$ is well-defined.

Comment: It seems OP has excluded your counterexample by asking for no other zeros in the ball. I do agree that the more restrictive condition is likely necessary though.

Comment: @operatorerror You are right. I wonder whether $df(z_0)$ can have rank one.

Comment: Yes, I am having some difficulty finding a counterexample myself

Comment: @zhw. What disturbs you?

Comment: @foreverstudent Did you see my answer?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I did, thank you for providing it. I have two little questions: it should be $h=f^{-1}(f(z_0+h)....$ correct? Also, the $o(||h||)$ term comes from Lipschitz continuity of $f$? I tried to bound this function you have $||f(z_0+h)||/||h||$ for when $df$ isn't necessarily full rank, but was unable to. Do you think it might be modified?

Comment: @foreverstudent I added explanations. I only use the definition of differentiability.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I understand this, I was just confirming that $o(||f(z_0+h)||=o(||h||)$ by a Lipschitz continuity argument. I also think there is still a mismatched parentheses: do you mean $h=f^{-1}(f(z_0+h))-f^{-1}(f(z_0)$ as I said above?

Comment: @foreverstudent $||f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)|| = ||df(z_0)h + o(||h||)|| \le ||df(z_0)h|| + ||o(||h||)|| \le ||df(z_0)|| \times ||h|| + ||o(||h||)|| = o(||h||)$. I corrected the mismatched parenthesis.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Yes, I see, this is another way to see it. Do you have a guess on whether the more general statement is true?

Answer (score 1):

"For example, if $f(x_0,y_0)=0$ but $f$ has no other zeros in the ball, is it enough to have $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\ne 0$?"

Suppose $f$ is real valued (which implies $f$ is complex valued). Then by the implicit function theorem, $f$ cannot satisfy the above, because the zero set of $f$ near $(x_0,y_0)$ will be a smooth nonconstant curve through $(x_0,y_0).$

Comment: This is wrong. $f$ is complex-valued, not real-valued.

Comment: I forgot about $f$ being complex valued. Thank you, I'll edit. However, a real valued function is complex valued.

Comment: @zhw. but not a counterexample to the given statement, right? If $f$ is real valued, it cannot satisfy the hypotheses (indeed, if $f$ is real, and has an isolated zero, the gradient should vanish at the zero I think).

Comment: @zhw. Your proof does not tell us whether for an arbitrary smpooth complex valued function is it enough to have ∇(0,0)≠0 when (0,0) is the only zero in the ball...

Comment: I started out by forgetting $f$ is complex valued. After that, all I intended was an observation: If $f$ is real valued, then the hypotheses that @foreverstudent mentioned cannot be satisfied. That's all.